# Collections.unmodifiablemap() and collections where reads also modify

Tags: java, collections

This is more a curiosity question than anything. Say I supply a LinkedHashMap with access ordering set to true to Collections.unmodifiableMap(). Since reads are actually modifying the map. Does it mean there are cases where the view returned by unmodifiableMap() is actually modifiable?

> ```
> public class MyApp {
>
>    /**
>    * @param args
>    */    
>    public static void main(String[] args)    {
>      Map<String, String> m = new LinkedHashMap<String,
>       String>(16,.75f,true);
>       Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);    
>
>     }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: HashMap and LinkedHashMap always has an underlying capacity which is a power of 2. setting it to 15 is the same as using 16 which is the default. Changing the load factor from the default of 0.7 to 0.75 is unlikely to make much difference.

Comment: I just supplied psuedo random values. Though I am pretty sure default initial capacity is 16 and load factor is .75. Though those are really unrelated to my question.

Comment: You are correct about the load factor. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Map is modifying itself. `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` only provides a decorator for the Map which disallows modifications, it does not make the Map itself unmodifiable.

Comment: sure but part of that decorator still allows get() operations which modify the the map. There is nothing special about get() and put() that ensure one or the other modifies or doesn't modify the map. I guess that what I'm getting at is that unmodifiables kind of rely on the assumption that put() modifies the map and get() doesn't

Comment: @nsfyn55: Alright, it would be more technically correct to say that the decorator disallows calls to methods that would alter the `Map` according to the `Map` interface. The `Map` interface says nothing about order, and thus `LinkedHashMap` is not considered to be "modified" according to it.

Answer (score 3):

`Collections.unmodifiableMap` returns a new Map that throws exceptions when you try to modify it, using the existing Map that you passed in as a backing collection.  It doesn't change the semantics of the existing Map.